# (Excel, workshift) Weekly work hours around fixed amount

Tags: excel, excel-2010

Well this problem is a little hard to explain in just one line for the title, but i hope it worked.

Anyway, i have made an excel spreadsheet where i keep track of the time i have worked each week. It has a week number, date, check-in, check-out and hours worked that day.
At the bottom of each week the total sum of hours are calculated and displayed.

Now, the place where i work, i have to work 37 hours each week, if i go under i have to make up for it the next, if i go over i can work that amount less the next week.

So i would like to have something like this under my total hours:
-3 (if i am three hours behind for example), or +4 (if i am four hours over).

Does it make sense? I have tried myself this past time but couldnt get it to work properly.

Comment: Please provide sample data."Total Sum" what format is it, Numeric or DateTime?

Comment: How would you want it? Its a little difficult to present excel sheets here... I can try
Column A: Week number.
Column B: Date.
Column C: Check-in.
Column D: Check-out.
Column E: Hours and minutes worked that day.
At the bottom of that week in column E, the total amount of hours and minutes worked that week are there.

Comment: The total sum of hours in a week is formatted as "[h]:mm", if thats what you are asking?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Total hours worked per week difference from fixed 37 hours: `=IF((37-SUM(E3:E7)*24)<0,"-"&TEXT(ABS((37-SUM(E3:E7)*24)/24),"hh:mm"),"+"&TEXT((37-SUM(E3:E7)*24)/24,"hh:mm"))`.

E3:E7 hours worked per day in TimeFormat. This formula gets the total, and checks if it is less or more than 37 hours, if less then adds "-" to make it look negative, otherwise "+" to make it look positive.

Comment: But doing this, the sum for a day and a week wouldnt be shown in hours and minutes, right?

Comment: It will show as numeric decimals, for example: `checkIn`=15:00, `checkOut`=20:15, `hoursWorked=(checkOut-checkIn)*24`=5.25. Which means it is 5 hours and 25% of 60 minutes, 15 minutes, i.e.: you worked 05:15.

Comment: I cant just calculate directly from the total sum of hours for the week? So only the cell that tells me how many hours over or under 37 i am, is numeric?

Comment: Great, looks like it works as intended, before i mark it as answer i have one last question: It fails when 37 is exceeded, is there anyway to avoid this? The perfect scenario is if it just keeps counting, even if its negative as described in my original post.

Comment: Because, you cannot display Time format with negative value.That is why I was converting it to numeric

Comment: I see you changed your formula, but it throws an error here: 0,"